# fail to connect jenkins to github

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am learning jenkins from linkdin and i did exact same thing as it has to be done in the process of connecting jenkins to git.
but everytime build can't find path location of the file and file path is correct and same as it has been told in the course.

please help i am new to this and i have tried my ways to connect it

[image: this is git link and i am using the same link but it's not working]

[image: output after build]

I tried to connect with windows path and git path but It did not work.

Comment: Also, please don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the file name `jenkinsfile` is case sensitive. Navigate to `project configuration > pipeline` and set the `script path` to "jenkinsfile" (lowercase `j`) instead of "Jenkinsfile" and the pipeline should work.